# Visual Studio Performance Profiler results are blank

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiler

I'm trying to profile my program's (Console, .NET 7) CPU usage using the Performance Profiler, but once it finishes, the result tab is blank.
[image: Performance Profiler settings]

Saving the report does result in a file with data in it, so I assume the profiler worked, but the results are not displaying.
[image: Performance Profiler blank results]

Any idea what might be causing it, or how I could get it back?

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio, rebooting my PC, profiling different projects, including old, Framework, projects. The results are always blank.

Comment: Does your computer use some computer security software? Try closing them and restarting Performance Profiler.

Comment: To the extent Windows will let me disable Windows Defender, I did. It, sadly, had no effect.

Comment: Please click the settings icon next to CPU Usage to view your settings

Comment: "Collect call counts" is disabled and the CPU sample rate is set to the default 1000. There are no other options. Changing either did not make results appear when profiling again.

Comment: Hi, which version of Windows are you using and what type of project are you using? I need to reproduce this issue more completely.

Comment: Windows 10 Home, Version 21H2, OS build 19044.3086. I have tried different projects, from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 7. They're all simple console projects with no external dependencies.